# Rendering a different data when a checkbox is checked not working in my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my react project, I have a default table component that will always display on the screen when no checkbox is checked. But, when any other checkbox is checked, I need to pass the checked value into the default table as a prop. So,  the table can return the new filtered table. What I have done so far did not give the filtred table based on the checked value. I need someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Code sandbox [Replit link](https://replit.com/join/pukizlqjht-femitosin1)

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./Datesvalues";
import Datesvalues from "./Datesvalues";
import Defaultdata from "./defaultData";
import Table from "./Table";
import TableData from "./TableData";
export default function App() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState(false);
  const [checkedIds, setChekedIds] = useState([]);
  const [isrecent, setisrecent] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isfiltereddatecheck, setisfiltereddatecheck] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(
      TableData.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(b.time_stamp) - new Date(a.time_stamp);
      })
    );

      setisfiltereddatecheck(
        data.filter((deliv)=> deliv.delivery_time_frame.substr(0,10) === checkedIds)
      )



  }, [data, isfiltereddatecheck]);

  const handlechange = (e) => {
    setstate(!state);
    const clickedId = e.target.value;
    if (checkedIds.includes(clickedId)) {
      setChekedIds(checkedIds.filter((id) => id !== clickedId));
    } else {
      setChekedIds([...checkedIds, clickedId]);
    }
  };

  const [functionToCall, createFunctionToCall] = useState(() => () => {});

  useEffect(() => {}, [functionToCall, createFunctionToCall]);

  const isCheked = (id) => {
    checkedIds.includes(id);
  };

  const dates = Defaultdata.filter((row) =>
    checkedIds.includes(row.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10))
  ).map((row) => row.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10));

  const unique = [...new Set(dates)];

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(checkedIds);
    console.log(unique, "dates");
  }, [checkedIds, dates]);

  const handleRecent = () => {
    setisrecent(!isrecent);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleRecent} checked={isrecent} />
        <label>Recent added</label>
      </div>
      {[
        ...new Set(Defaultdata.map((a) => a.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10)))
      ].map((dates, i) => (
        <label style={{ listStyle: "none" }} key={i}>
          <input
            onChange={handlechange}
            type="checkbox"
            value={dates}
            checked={isCheked(dates)}
          />
          <span>{dates}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
      <div>
        {isrecent ? (
          <Datesvalues date="Recently added component" />
        ) : !checkedIds.length ? (
          <Table data_={data} createFunctionToCall={createFunctionToCall} />
        ) : (
          <Table
            data_={isfiltereddatecheck}
            date={unique}
            createFunctionToCall={createFunctionToCall}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Table.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";

import { AiTwotoneStar } from "react-icons/ai";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import { AiOutlineInfoCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import axios from "axios";
import TableData from "./TableData";
const Table = ({
  data_,
  handleImageChange,
  updateItemToShow,

  createFunctionToCall,
  date
}) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [checkboxstate, setcheckboxstate] = useState();
  const [boxcheck, setboxcheck] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [itemLength, setitemLength] = useState(0);
  const [deefault, setDeefault] = useState([]);
  const [paginateActivePage, setPaginateActivePage] = useState(1);
  const [activeDeliveries, setActiveDeliveries] = useState([]);
  const [newdatatoshow, setnewdatatoshow] = useState([]);
  const [sampledata, setsampledata] = useState({
    type_1: "watch",
    id: []
  });
  const [n, setn] = useState(20);

  const [newd, setnewd] = useState([]);
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    setDeefault(data_);
    setitemLength(data_.length);
    setActiveDeliveries(data_.slice(0, n));
  }, [data_]);

  const scrollToRef = (ref) =>
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });

  const backToTop = useRef(null);
  const executeScrollbacktotop = () => scrollToRef(backToTop);

  const [tablesearch] = useState(!data_);
  const [showpopup, setShowpopup] = useState(false);
  const [componenttoshow, setComponenttoshow] = useState(false);
  const [checkClick, setCheckClick] = useState(true);
  const [watch, setWatch] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [watchType, setwatchType] = useState("add");
  const handleLastShowValue = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    setn(Number(value));
    console.log(n, "selectedn");
    setActiveDeliveries(
      deefault.slice(
        paginateActivePage * Number(value) - Number(value),
        paginateActivePage * Number(value)
      )
    );
  };
  const [newdilId, setnewdilId] = useState([]);
  const [removedilId, setremovedilId] = useState([]);
  const [watchbtn, setwatchbtn] = useState(true);
  const [newbtn, setnewbtn] = useState(true);
  const [strid, setstrid] = useState("");
  const [watchnowcall, setwatchnowcall] = useState(false);
  var FulfilerId;
  const [rm, setrm] = useState(false);

  

  
  const handlingmultiplechecklist = (e) => {
    console.log(`checked = ${e.target.checked}`);
    if (e.target.checked) {
      newdilId.filter((d, i) => d !== e.target.checked);
    } else {
    }
  };

  const override = css`
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: red;
    position: relative !important ;
    z-index: 8;
  `;

  const [seachstate, setStatevalue] = useState(false);
  const [searchdata, setsearchdata] = useState(data);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const inputEl = useRef("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(newdatatoshow);
    //console.log(sampledata)
  }, [newdatatoshow]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log( sampledata.id )
  }, [sampledata.id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function TheFunctionToCall() {
      setShowpopup(!showpopup);
      if (localStorage.getItem("_nodi") === null) {
        setComponenttoshow(true);
      } else {
        setComponenttoshow(false);

        console.log(newdatatoshow, "bros please work");
      }
    }
    createFunctionToCall(() => TheFunctionToCall);
  }, [createFunctionToCall, newdatatoshow]);

  //const [value, setValue] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{date}</h1>

      <table className="table_">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <span>
                {" "}
                <input type="checkbox" />
              </span>
            </th>
            <th>Timeframe</th>
            <th> Item </th>

            <th>Pick up </th>
            <th>Destination</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <div></div>
        <tbody>
          {activeDeliveries.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                {}

                <td>
                  <span
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      setnewdatatoshow([...newdatatoshow, item.delivery_id]);
                      setcheckboxstate(e.target.checked);
                      setboxcheck(true);
                      setsampledata({
                        ...sampledata,
                        id: [...sampledata.id, item.delivery_id]
                      });
                      if (!e.target.checked) {
                        setboxcheck(true);
                        setnewdatatoshow(
                          newdatatoshow.filter(function (n) {
                            return n !== item.delivery_id;
                          })
                        );
                        setsampledata({
                          ...sampledata,
                          id: sampledata.id.filter(function (n) {
                            return n !== item.delivery_id;
                          })
                        });
                      }
                      console.log(sampledata.id.includes("NG3088568879"));
                    }}
                  >
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      style={{ width: "15px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                    />
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span className="item-style">{item.delivery_time_frame}</span>
                </td>


                <td>
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      <span className="item-style" style={{}}>
                        <div>
                          {" "}
                          <span
                            className=" item_desc_watch"
                            onClick={() => {
                              updateItemToShow(item);
                              handleImageChange();
                            }}
                          >
                            {item.item_desc.length > 9 ? (
                              <span className="item-style item-style-hover">
                                {item.item_desc.slice(0, 25)}
                              </span>
                            ) : (
                              <span className="item-style">
                                {item.item_desc.slice(0, 25)}
                              </span>
                            )}
                          </span>
                        </div>

                        {rm ? (
                          <button>Api check</button>
                        ) : (
                          <button>remove</button>
                        )}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </td>

                <td>
                  {" "}
                  <main>
                    {item.from.length <= 40 ? (
                      <span className="item-style">{item.from}</span>
                    ) : (
                      <span className="item-style">
                        {item.from.slice(0, 40)}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </main>
                </td>

                <td>
                  <main>
                    {item.to.length <= 40 ? (
                      <span className="item-style">{item.to}</span>
                    ) : (
                      <span className="item-style">{item.to.slice(0, 40)}</span>
                    )}
                  </main>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

TableData

```
const TableData = [
  {
    date_listed: "5 hours ago",
    delivery_id: "NG5126872813",
    delivery_time_frame: "2022-10-4",
    distance: "24.3 km",
    duration: "31 mins",
    duration_in_traffic: "28 mins",
    end_location: { lat: "6.596841899999999", lng: "3.3405595" },
    from: "Abc Road",
    item_category: "general_items",
    item_desc: "Many Fruits",
    mode_of_delivery: "car",
    pickup_date: "2021-11-30",
    quote: 0,
    src_coutry: " Nigeria",
    src_state: " Lagos",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-31 15:48:23",
    to: "Home Address"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "5 hours ago",
    delivery_id: "NG5126872813",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-10-31",
    distance: "24.3 km",

    duration: "31 mins",
    duration_in_traffic: "28 mins",
    end_location: { lat: "6.596841899999999", lng: "3.3405595" },
    from: "Def Road",
    item_category: "general_items",
    item_desc: "Many Fruits",
    mode_of_delivery: "car",
    pickup_date: "2021-11-30",
    quote: 0,
    src_coutry: " Nigeria",
    src_state: " Lagos",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-31 15:48:23",
    to: "Home Address"
  },

  {
    date_listed: "5 hours ago",
    delivery_id: "NG5126872813",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-18 - 2021-10-31",
    distance: "24.3 km",
    duration: "31 mins",
    duration_in_traffic: "28 mins",
    end_location: { lat: "6.596841899999999", lng: "3.3405595" },
    from: "Ghi Road",

    item_category: "general_items",
    item_desc: "Many Fruits",
    mode_of_delivery: "car",
    pickup_date: "2021-11-30",
    quote: 0,
    src_coutry: " Nigeria",
    src_state: " Lagos",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-31 15:48:23",
    to: "Home Address"
  }
];

export default TableData;
```

Comment: sandbox is bad, sources are missing

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Thank you for your quick response. I realised i posted the wrong link but I just updated the link now